# How to stop an move_and_colide object with a staticbody2d or tilemap?

Tags: godot

I'm really really new to Godot and I'm working on a game where a box pushes the Player ( an Kinematic Object) out of the Screen. But if I try to apply gravity to the box the Engine says

> "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'moveandcolllide' in base 'StaticBody2D'

Answer (score 1):

The functions `move_and_collide` and `move_and_slide` exists on `KinematicBody` and `KinematicBody2D`. And you are trying to call it on something that does not have it (an `StaicBody2D` apparently).

---

If you want to push something, `StaicBody2D` is the worst option. The `StaicBody2D` (and the tiles from a `TileMap`) are not to be pushed around.

The best option would be using a `RigidBody2D`, on which you can *configure* a gravity, and use forces and impulses to control it. You don't need code to make a `RigidBody2D` react to collisions. Your `KinematicBody2D` will push `RigidBody2D` push around *with no extra code*.

Most of the time you want to make whatever you want to be pushed into a `RigidBody2D`. In fact, if you want the player character to be pushed, that might be the case where making it a `RigidBody2D` instead of a `KinematicBody2D` is a good idea. *And yes, `RigidBody2D` can push things too.*

However, if you need to push a `KinematicBody2D`, then you will need extra work. We have two cases to be concerned with: A `KinematicBody2D` that pushes other `KinematicBody2D`, and some other body that pushes `KinematicBody2D`.

---

For a pushing `KinematicBody2D`...

The motion from `move_and_slide` will stop (that is, not slide) if you pass `true` on `stop_on_slope` or if it hits a *wall*. And it decides what is a *wall* according the `up_direction` and `floor_max_angle` (radians) you pass when calling it. If you pass `0` on `floor_max_angle`, then only surfaces perpendicular to `up_direction` are considered floors (or slopes). And if you pass `Vector2.ZERO` in `up_direction`, then everything is a wall.

You can also use `get_slide_count` and `get_slide_collision` to find out what it collided with. Example from the official documentation:

```
for i in get_slide_count():
    var collision = get_slide_collision(i)
    print("Collided with: ", collision.collider.name)
```

Alternatively, you can use `move_and_collide` (don't forger that that `move_and_slide` takes a velocity but `move_and_collide` takes a relative position, which means it is up to you to multiply by `delta` when using it). It will return a `KinematicCollision2D` object which tells you what it collided with (just like `get_slide_collision` does).

Either way, the `KinematicBody2D` will be able to handle the situation when it runs into some other object as a result of its own motion.

---

For the case of something else pushing the `KinematicBody2D`, I suggest adding an `Area2D` as child of the `KinematicBody2D` as a way to detect incoming collisions.

---

**Important**: Check with what kind of body the collision is. You need to deal with `RigidBody2D` and `KinematicBody2D` by different means (you can call `move_and_slide` and `move_and_collide` on the `KinematicBody2D`. And if you were to manipulate a `RigidBody2D`, that would be with forces and impulses). And deal with `StaticBody2D` by no means, they are not to be pushed around (Same goes for `TileMap` collisions). *Again, if there is something you want to push, you probably want to make it a `RigidBody2D`.*